# How to pass a request.get into action attribute of form tag as i am new to Django

Tags: django

Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action = "{% url "sparta:storeid" store_id=request.GET.get('your_name') %}" method = "get">
        <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
        <input  type="text" name="your_name">
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def detail(request,store_id='1'):
    print(store_id)
    return HttpResponse("checkout {}".format(store_id))

def forms(request):
    dict1={'con':'sdsd'}
    return render(request, "forms.html",context=dict1)
```

urls.py (from application)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from second_app import views

app_name='sparta'

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^stores/$',views.forms),
    url(r'^stores/(?P<store_id>\d+)/$',views.detail,name="storeid"),
]
```

urls.py (from main url)

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from second_app import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^stores/',include("second_app.urls")),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I am able to get results while using request.GET.get('your_name') in views.py and using render. I am experimenting for this case from directly passing the request variable through url tag .

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action = "{% url "sparta:storeid" store_id=request.GET.get('your_name') %}" method = "get">
    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
    <input  type="text" name="your_name">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Usually, forms ***should* only pass data to other resources when you click "submit".** Knowing this, you should move the snippet `"{% url "sparta:storeid" store_id=request.GET.get('your_name') %}"` to a view.

In Django this is specially true. The `{% item %}` syntax is useful, but quite limited. Always try to keep the logic in your `views.py` files.

That would be an ideal scenario, assuming that you're building that app from scratch.

Another alternative would be to use this, which employs Javascript:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

But then again, that has its own set of implications.

You could do a lot better if you follow [Django's tutorial regarding views and forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/). That will teach you a bunch of really useful principles!